# Magento2 Logout Customer using rest API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am using magento2 core api for logout customer using id but it is not working

[image]

Comment: Does it your custom API? By default don't have that endpoint.

Comment: No I want to use Magento Core APIs can you please share the tutorials/ link of all magento APIs